Как нажать стрелки в python?
Как нажать стрелки с клавиатуры (те которые справа)?
С помощью какого модуля и метода в нём можно нажать стрелки в python?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

С помощью какого модуля и метода в нём можно нажать стрелки в python?

https://habr.com/ru/articles/579942/ , https://pyautogui-ru.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/

Это уже лучше. Однако, пожалуйста, обновите текст вашего вопроса. Добавьте как можно больше подробностей о том, что вы уже пробовали @sus

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Насколько я понял, вопрос звучит на самом деле так:
с помощью какого модуля можно эмулировать нажатие кнопок-стрелок?
Примеры:

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
keyboard.press(Key.left)
keyboard.release(Key.left)


import keyboard

keyboard.press_and_release('left')


import pyautogui

pyautogui.press('left')

